# How to find the average transmitted energy per symbol (E) and Spectral Noise Density (No)?

Tags: matlab, telecommunication

I am trying to duplicate the Figure 3 in Matlab of the paper ["Intelligent Reflecting Surface Assisted Terahertz Communications"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9840765).

[image]

But, I cannot figure out how to find the values of E and No in the equation 6 given in the below figure.

[image]

Could you please help.

Comment: where is figure 3? the question shows figure 2 and the link to the article containing all the figures remains behind the IEEE log in portal. Would you please reproduce figure 3 for all readers to see?

Comment: have you tried asking the authors of the article?